# Perfect squares with algebra

Tags: quadratics, square-numbers

Hi this ' True or False' question is in the 'GCSE Mathematics for AQA Higher Student Book' that we use at school

> $30\frac{1}{4}$ must be added to $x^2 - 11x$ to make a perfect square.

I am sure that this is true because $x^2-11x$ in the form of $(x+p)^2+q$ would be $(x+5.5)^2$. And this expands to be $x^2-11x+34.35$, where the $34.25$ is added to the original expression.

However, the answer book gave me this:

> False; $30\frac{1}{4}$ must be subtracted

which contradicts with everything I've explained above. And another logic I don't understand about their answer is that how can you factorize $x^2-11x-34.25$ into a perfect square if the '$34.25$' is a negative number (because you can't square root a negative no.?)

Please explain what has happened here, if it is me or the book who is wrong. And if my math was wrong then why. Thank you

Comment: The question is imprecise. The truth is that you must *both add and subtract* $\frac{121}{4}$ in order to rewrite the given expression as a perfect square:
$$x^2-11x=x^2-11x\color{red}{+\frac{121}{4}}\color{blue}{-\frac{121}{4}}=\left(x-\frac{11}{2}\right)^2\color{blue}{-\frac{121}{4}}$$

Comment: hang on. So is a perfect square written in the format (x+p)^2  or can it be also (x+p)^2+q ? Because I thought you can't add numbers 'q' on to the end otherwise it wouldn't be 'perfect'

Comment: The binomial $(x+p)^2$ *is* a perfect square. The expression $(x+p)^2+q$ is *not* a perfect square.

Comment: okay. But then why do you subtract the 121/4 at the end? Surely that wouldn't be a perfect square?

Comment: Look, the point is that $x^2-11x$ is itself *not* a perfect square, and therefore it *cannot be rewritten as a perfect square*. However, it *can* be rewritten in the form $(x+p)^2+q$, and that's what the problem means.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Okay thanks for the explanation , I think I get it now, so the question is kind of asking for the wrong thing?

Comment: Given the way the problem is stated, the alleged answer is incorrect. $x^2-11x$ is not a perfect square, but $30.5+x^2-11x$ is a perfect square. So the statement is true, not false. The so-called explanation is completely incorrect.

Comment: $5.5^2 = 30.25$ and not $34.25$ or $34.35$